# Can I merge the System reserved partition to C: drive? Will it cause boot problems if I do so?

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, partitioning, partition-recovery

I have lost a drive as an unallocated space, in order to recover it, I need to remove an already existing System partition.

Comment: **Not recommended.**  The system reserved partition in on BIOS systems is meant to house WinRE and the boot files.  In UEFI, it's meant to house WinRE only, however the 16MB MSR partition should not be removed.  While you can configure the `C:` partition to house WinRE _(via `ReAgentC`)_, it's not recommended for a variety of reasons, most important is if the `C:` partition becomes corrupted and WinRE is stored there, you're not going to be able to boot into WinRE to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

> I have lost a drive as an unallocated space, in order to recover it, I need to remove an already existing System partition.

The system reserved partition should absolutely not be deleted.

> What if it doesn't boot again and then I wouldn't be able to recover the lost drive?

Before you make any change to your partition table you should make sure you have a backup of you vital data.

> Is there a way to convert it to GPT without data loss?

Due to the 4 primary partition limit of MBR, you need to convert your disk to GPT, this can be acomplished with the built-in MBR2GPT tool that exists within Windows 10.  However, in order for it to be sucessfull, you must only have 3 partitions.

Due to the fact you currently have 4 partitions you will have to merge your two data partitions together.  This will require you to move data off the second 274 GB partition in order to merge it with first 274 GB partition.  **In order for MBR2GPT to work you should keep the unallocated partition unallocated.**

**After you make the apprpriate backup, you can run [MBR2GPT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/mbr-to-gpt), and convert your disk to GPT without any data loss.**  Once converted you can shrink the single partition into 3 partitions if you want.  **You should only perform these steps if your machine supports UEFI.**

The Prerequisites for MBR2GPT are the following:

> 1. The disk is currently using MBR
> 2. There is enough space not occupied by partitions to store the primary and secondary GPTs:
>
>    - 16KB + 2 sectors at the front of the disk
>    - 16KB + 1 sector at the end of the disk
> 3. There are at most 3 primary partitions in the MBR partition table
> 4. One of the partitions is set as active and is the system partition
> 5. The disk does not have any extended/logical partition
> 6. The BCD store on the system partition contains a default OS entry pointing to an OS partition
> 7. The volume IDs can be retrieved for each volume which has a drive letter assigned
> 8. All partitions on the disk are of MBR types recognized by Windows or has a mapping specified using the /map command-line option

Source: [MBR2GPT Disk Prerequisites](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/mbr-to-gpt#disk-prerequisites)